# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "reden" und "sprechen"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, verb-usage, synonym

Ich denke, sie sind Synonyme; aber sind sie es wirklich? *"Reden"* scheint mehr umgangssprachlich zu sein, während *"sprechen"* ganz viele verschiedene Bedeutungen hat. Warum gibt es das Wort *"reden"*? Warum ist *"sprechen"* nicht genug? Was ist der Ursprung?

Comment: Their meaning are quite similar to *talk* and *speak*. If you google for difference between those words, you find a lot of sources which do fit for the German equivalents, too. For instance [this one](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/speak-talk-differences). I guess most times you can translate *sprechen* with *speak*, though sometimes *talk* is the better one; and the other way round of course.

Comment: Also have a look at pons, [reden](http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=reden&l=deen&in=&lf=en) and [sprechen](http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=sprechen&l=deen&in=&lf=en), to get some ideas when to use which one.

Comment: Fehlt noch "sagen". <i> Sie reden viel und sagen wenig. </i>

Comment: @userunknown Und noch eines... *Der Polizeisprecher **äußerte** sich nicht zu den Ermittlungen.*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

„Reden“ und „sprechen“ beziehen sich auf unterschiedliche Aspekte der Sprachproduktion.

„Sprechen“ beschreibt das Vermögen des Menschen, Sprache zu produzieren, und den Vorgang der Sprachproduktion an sich: Jemand kann nicht sprechen, jemand spricht schnell oder laut, jemand spricht schlecht Deutsch usw. „Sprechen“ ist eine psychophysische Fähigkeit wie Sehen oder Laufen.

„Reden“ bezieht sich auf den sozialen Akt, der mit Sprache vollzogen wird: Man redet mit oder zu jemandem und über etwas, um Information auszutauschen, Beziehungen zu pflegen, Macht auszuüben usw. „Reden“ ist eine Handlung im sozialen Kontext.

Beispiele:

---

**Sprechen**

> Jürgen spricht Deutsch.

Jürgen beherrscht die deutsche Sprache; aber dieser Satz lässt offen, ob Jürgen auch etwas Sinnvolles sagt.

> Thomas Danneberg ist ein ganz hervorragender Sprecher.

Thomas Danneberg ist Schauspieler und Synchronsprecher. Er leiht in deutschsprachigen Fassungen von Kinofilmen anderen Schauspielern seine Stimme. (Dannebergs Stimme ist die deutsche Stimme von Sylvester Stallone, Arnold Schwarzenegger, John Travolta, Nick Nolte und noch ein paar mehr.)
Ein guter Sprecher kann klar und deutlich sprechen. Er kann seine Stimme gut einsetzen, um vorgegebene Sätze prägnant vorzutragen. Er ist aber nicht für die dabei transportierten Inhalte verantwortlich.

> Thomas und Jürgen sprechen miteinander.

Thomas und Jürgen sind beschäftigt und haben geraden keine Zeit. Sprechen erklärt nur, womit sie beschäftigt sind, sie könnten ebenso gut Kuchen backen.

---

**Reden**

> Jürgen redet mit seinem Sohn.

Jürgen führt ein Gespräch mit seinem Sohn. Jürgen hat seinem Sohn etwas zu sagen. Jürgen will irgendwelche Aussagen weitergeben.

> Barack Obama ist ein ganz hervorragender Redner.

Obama ist Politiker und er kann seinen Beruf nur dann gut machen, wenn er es schafft, Inhalte gut in Worte zu verpacken. Das macht einen guten Redner aus. Natürlich ist es von Vorteil, wenn man als Redner auch gut sprechen kann; aber Reden ist mehr als Sprechen.

> Thomas und Jürgen reden miteinander.

Thomas und Jürgen hatten Streit. Jetzt versuchen sie, ihre Probleme zu lösen und sich wieder zu vertragen.

Comment: Tolle Erklärung. Ich stimme absolut zu. Die Bedeutungsunterschiede werden vielleicht anschaulicher, wenn man an die zugehörigen Substantive denkt: Sprache (die Fähigkeit, zu sprechen; eine bestimmte Sprache usw.) vs Rede (eine in mündlicher Sprache ausgedrückte Botschaft).

Comment: Was meinst du mit dem Satz `"--Reden ist mehr als Sprechen."`? Is `"reden"` more casual while `"sprechen"` more neutral and sometimes more official?

Comment: `'Mit "reden" ist die Weitergabe von Inhalten verbunden."`, was meinst du? `"reden"` ist nicht wie eine akademischen Debatte. Du kann nicht allein reden aber du kann allein sprechen. Artikulierung -- z.B. `"Ich braunche Artikulierung-Übungen auf Deutsch, wenn ich nicht in Deutschland leben."` -- kann dann beide sein: social und nicht social. Reden, sprechen, artikulieren, debattieren, vorsagen, hersagen -- mehr? Eine Aktivität kann social sein und muss in einige Meinungen sowie mit dem Wort `"reden"`. Ich sollte die Meinungen kategorisieren...

Comment: "Reden": You transfer meaningful content. "Sprechen": Just connect words in a grammatically correct order. Those words don't need to contain meaningful content. I'm not shure if this translation is correct: "sprechen" - "to speak". "reden" - "to talk".

Comment: Not necessarily *meaningful* content. See "reden, ohne etwas zu sagen" or "dumm daherreden". And "sprechen" doesn't necessarily imply correct grammar either.

Comment: Ich kann dieser Antwort leider nicht zustimmen. Vor Allem suggeriert sie eine Dichotomie, die so nicht gegeben ist. Z. B. wird eine *öffentliche* Rede auch als **Ansprache** bezeichnet. Ebenso heißt es nicht *Der Redner redet auf dem Kongress, sondern Der Redner* **spricht** *auf dem Kongress*. Ebenfalls wird nicht klar, wo der Unterschied zum anderen Verb *sagen* sein soll, das ebenfalls für *Sprache produzieren* verwendet wird. Die Verwendung von *reden* vs. *sprechen* ist eher durch den Kontext bzw. durch die sprachliche Konvention gegeben als durch eine feste Zuordnung.

Comment: Ferner hat *sprechen* - wie schon in der Frage suggeriert - definiitv eine gehobeneren Aspekt als *reden*. *Mein Vorgesetzer will mich sprechen* hat definitiv einen anderen Stil als *Mein Chef will mit mir reden*, obwohl offensichtlich klar ist, dass es die selbe Bedeutung hat.

Comment: Ironischerweise wird in der Antwort der Beispielsatz *Jürgen redet mit seinem Sohn* gegeben, der mit *Jürgen führt ein* **Gespräch** *mit seinem Sohn* erläutert wird (Warum nicht **Gerede**? Achso, das ist ja was anderes!) Einfach nur schlecht recherchiert. Downvote.

Answer (score 11):

Dies ist nicht als "bessere" Antwort zu der von Hubert Schölnast gemeint, sondern vielmehr eine Ergänzung. Seine Erklärung bezieht sich auf die hochdeutsche Standardsprache und ist für diese korrekt.

Das Hochdeutsche ist eine Verkehrssprache, die aus Elementen der verschiedenen deutschen Dialekte gebildet wurde. Luther hat in seiner Bibelübersetzung immer dort, wo es in den verschiedenen Dialekten unterschiedliche Wörter für dasselbe lateinische Original gab, beide deutschen Wörter verwendet. Auf diese Weise war seine Übersetzung in allen Regionen verständlich, weil der Leser immer eines von beiden Wörtern kannte. In der Folge sind dann beide Begriffe in die entstehende hochdeutsche Verkehrssprache eingegangen – manchmal mit genau synonymer, oft aber mit sich im Laufe der Sprachgeschichte ausdifferenzierenden Bedeutungen oder Verwendungskontexten.

In den regionalen deutschen Dialekten sind "sprechen" und "reden" auch heute noch unterschiedlich gebräuchlich. So sagt man in Süddeutschland "Jürgen redet Deutsch" (im Unterschied zu Hubert Schölnasts standardsprachlichem Beispiel "Jürgen spricht Deutsch"), und das Wort "sprechen" wird dort nur als Lehnwort aus dem Hochdeutschen verwendet. In den nördlichen Dialekten (soweit sie noch existieren und nicht durch das Hochdeutsche verdrängt wurden) werden ganz andere Wörter verwendet (z.B. "snacken" im Plattdeutschen).

Comment: ...und in der Akademia, es gibt Wörter sowie `"artikulieren"`, `"debattieren"` -- deren Ursprungen in Englisch sind -- oder ist es eigentlich Latein?

Answer (score 5):

Christian Morgenstern hat den Unterschied so erklärt:

> Jede Sprache ist schön, wenn in ihr nicht nur geredet, sondern gesprochen wird.

Das heißt, es besteht kein semantischer, sondern ein stilistischer Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern.

Comment: Auch wenn diese Antwort recht kurz ist, sie ist näher an der Wahrheit als der lange Text von Hubert Schönlast..

Answer (score 3):

**Vorneweg**: Die akzeptierte Antwort (siehe oben) ist m.M.n. totaler Unsinn (siehe meine Kommetare darunter).

---

Die Bevorzugung von *reden* über *sprechen* ist sehr kontextabhängig und erfordert ein gewisses Gefühl für die Sprache. Es ist insofern wahr, dass *sprechen* in vielen Situationen einen gehobeneren Stil als *reden* ausdrückt, siehe folgendes Beispiel:

*Mein Vorgesetzer will mich **sprechen**.*

*Mein Chef will mit mir **reden**.*

*Reden* suggeriert in der Tat oft ein eher umgangssprachliches Gespräch, weshalb man oft Dinge wie

*Ich muss jetzt mit meinem Sohn reden.*

hört. Dennoch kann auch für das Ausdrücken des sozialen Aktes des *sich unterhaltens* *sprechen* statt *reden* verwendet werden:

*Herr Huber hat seit Tagen nicht mehr mit seiner Frau gesprochen.*

Wie schwierig die korrekte Verwendung dieser beiden Verben ist lässt sich auch gut an folgendem Beispiel erkennen:

*Du hast so lange nicht mehr mit deiner Frau **gesprochen**. **Rede** doch mal mit ihr!*

Die Einteilung ist dennoch sehr schwierig, was auch durch die von den beiden Verben abgeleiteten Nomen erkenntlich wird: Während z.B. **Gespräch** ein neutrales Wort ist, ist **Gerede** bereits herablassend gemeint. Eine **Rede** vor dem Publikum ist aber wohl eine sehr ernste Sache und wird mitunter auch als **Ansprache** bezeichnet.

Wie man sieht, ist nicht alles schwarz und weiß in der **Sprache**. Aber genug mit dem **Gerede**!

P.S: Die genauen Verwendungen von *reden* und *sprechen* sollten ferner auch im Duden nachgelesen werden!

Comment: Ich würde sagen: »Herr Huber hat seit Tagen nicht mehr mit seiner Frau **geredet**.« »Gesprochen« ist nach meinem Sprachgefühl hier das falsche Wort. Ebenso im nächsten Beispiel: »Du hast so lange nicht mehr mit deiner Frau **geredet**.«

Comment: "Du hast so lange nicht mehr mit deiner Frau gesprochen. Rede doch mal mit ihr!" Ich verstehe das jetzt so, dass Hr. Huber so absolut gar nicht mit seiner Frau mündlich kommuniziert hat. Und deshalb sollte er mal mit ihr ein Gespräch führen, wahrscheinlich darüber, dass man nicht miteinander spricht. Außerdem schweizerisch: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gerede