# Difference between "sprechen", "sagen", "reden"

Tags: vocabulary

I would like to know what the difference between "sprechen", "sagen", "reden"? My guess would be, to say, to tell, to talk. I might be wrong, but please clarify!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "reden" und "sprechen"?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-reden-und-sprechen)

Comment: @c.p. It doesn't say anything about *sagen*.

Answer (score 18):

They accurately enough correspond to the following English verbs:

1. *sprechen*, to speak
2. *sagen*, to say.
3. *reden*, to talk.

Example:

> Das Baby kann schon **sprechen**. Gestern **sagte** es *Mama*, **redet** aber noch nicht.

Here *sprechen* is the human skill, to produce words. Roughly, *sagen* refers to the process of speaking determined number of times, a "discretization of *reden*". And *reden* really needs some eloquence.

Comment: So would you say: ich würde mit dir sprechen oder reden?

Comment: @John Both work, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a nice [article from Deutsche Welle](http://www.dw.de/beim-reden-nicht-zu-laut-sprechen/a-15511938), but it don’t covers *sagen*.

> […] Ein Kind lernt deshalb zuerst sprechen – also die Fähigkeit, Sprachlaute zu artikulieren, wie zum Beispiel "Papa" oder "Mama". Das Reden – nämlich eine sinnvolle längere Äußerung zu machen – kommt später. Diese Bedeutungsnuance zeigt sich auch bei den entsprechenden Substantiven: Der Sprecher trägt einen fremden Text vor oder – wie beim Regierungssprecher – eine vorgegebene Meinung, der Redner hingegen vermittelt dem Publikum einen eigenständigen Inhalt. […]

There is also a saying: “Er hat viel **geredet**, aber nichts **gesagt**.” It means that someone talked a lot but hasn’t given any information.