# Wie sagt man den Ausdruck "Now we are talking"?

Tags: grammar, expression

> A: Kannst du mir deine Telefonnummer geben?
>
> B: Wieso willste sie?
>
> A: Ich möchte deine Stimme hören.
>
> B: Achso, meine Telefonnummer ist *****6850
>
> A: Nun sprechen wir.

Kann man das in diesem Kontext sagen?

Comment: Nee, so kommst du der Sache nicht näher.

Comment: Da hast du die Nummer schon und holst dir doch noch einen Korb...

Comment: Telefonieren A und B schon als A sagt: "Nun sprechen wir." oder sagt A es und ruft B dann kurz darauf an? In erstem Fall würde ich stattdessen "Schön dich zu hören sagen", im zweiten "Danke, dann ruf ich dich an. Bis gleich (am Telefon)."

Comment: @Iris bitte "Now we are talking" im Wörterbuch nachschauen - Das ist eine *standing expression* und bedeutet soviel wie "Jetzt sind wir im Geschäft" o.Ä. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=now+we're+talking

Comment: DerPolyglott33, kannst Du bitte den Text zurück ins Englische übersetzen? Wenn ich das versuche, macht "now we're talking" an der Stelle irgendwie keinen Sinn...

Comment: @tofro, eine Frage hier sollte selbsterklärend sein!

Comment: @Iris, richtig. Ich finde, wenn man die Überschrift mitliest, ist sie das auch.

Comment: @tofro, mir geht es aber wie Stephie. Ich kann die deutschen Übersetzung nicht sinnvoll ins Englische übersetzen. Sagt man tatsächlich A: "Here's my number ...." B: "Now, we are talking."?

Comment: @tofro: Ich habe, wie Iris, auch die Überschrift gelesen, und konnte, wie Iris, auch nicht erraten, dass »now we are talking« etwas anderes als »jetzt reden wir« heißen könnte. Einen Blick in ein Wörterbuch habe ich nicht für notwendig gehalten, weil ich alle Wörter kenne.

Comment: Iris, Hubert - Akzeptiert. Ein Fremdsprachler hätte mit "Ausdruck" möglicherweise auch "Wort" meinen können. Wenn man die englische Phrase nicht kennt, ist die ganze Frage irreführend. Ob die ganze Konversation so wie beschrieben überhaupt im Englischen "zielführend" wäre? Ich glaube nicht.

Comment: Wieso stehen die dt. Texte vor den englischen, wenn die englischen übersetzt werden sollen? Was tragen die ersten Sätze zum Verständnis bei? Ich finde sie machen die Frage erst unverständlich.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Die wörtlichen Übersetzungen dazuzuschreiben, erhellt die Frage überhaupt nicht. So gut Englisch können die deutschen Muttersprachler hier schon, dass sie das auch selber verstehen. Was Iris, mir und vermutlich auch vielen anderen Menschen, die Englisch nicht auf dem Level C2 sprechen, unklar ist, ist die Bedeutung der englischen Phrase »Now, we're talking.« Das Problem ist ja genau, dass dieser Satz *nicht* »Jetzt reden wir.« bedeutet, sondern etwas anderes. Und diese andere Bedeutung solltest du (gerne in englischer Sprache) beschreiben um die Frage verständlich zu machen.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Kannst Du bitte klären, ob es Dir um die feststehende Phrase »Now we are talking.« (im Sinne von »much better«) oder die buchstäbliche Interpretation dieser Worte (also: »at this moment we are speaking to each other«) geht? Dein Beispiel legt letzteres nahe; die Tatsache, dass Du die Frage überhaupt stellst, ersteres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Now we are talking" hat im Deutschen keine wörtliche Übersetzung und für deinen Fall nicht einmal ein ähnliches Gegenstück. Im beschriebenen Gespräch würdest du dir für die wörtliche Übersetzung im besten Fall einen unverständigen Blick und im schlechtesten Fall einen Korb (also eine Absage) einhandeln (Ich bin im Übrigen nicht ganz sicher, ob das nicht auch im Englischen der Fall wäre, bzw. was für ein Bild das von den beteiligten Gesprächspartnern abgeben würde).

In vielen Fällen würde:

> Jetzt kommen wir ins Geschäft

oder

> Jetzt sind wir im Geschäft

passen. In deinem Beispiel passt das aber eher gar nicht und wäre für einen positiven Gesprächsausgang wahrscheinlich auch nicht sehr förderlich...

> Jetzt kommen wir der Sache schon näher

oder

> Jetzt läuft es ja

oder

> So wird das was

wären möglicherweise brauchbare Ersatzformulierungen.

Ich bin aber mit @Hubert Schölnast der Meinung, dass man das im Deutschen einfach nicht so sagen würde.

In deiner beschriebenen Situation passt

> Prima, das freut mich jetzt

einfach viel besser und ist mittelfristig auch "erfolgsversprechender".

Comment: Im Schwäbischen kann man die Phrase mit einem Wort ersetzen: "Jetzedle!" ;)

Comment: Wenn ich jemand meine Nummer gebe und mein Gegenüber antwortet "Jetzt kommen wir der Sache schon näher" oder "So wird das was", wäre mein erster Gedanke wohl "Was will er denn erreichen? Will er mich nur ins Bett kriegen?".

Comment: @Iris Noch schräger wäre: "Jetzt sind wir im Geschäft", was wie gesagt eine der Hauptverwendungen des englischen Ausdrucks ist. Danke. Das wollte ich sagen, ohne es zu sagen....

Comment: @Iris: Das gleiche auf English mit "now we are talking" als letztem Satz hat den gleichen Unterton. Perfekte Übersetzung eines ziemlich unpassenden Satzes.

Comment: in Jugendsprache: "Läuft"

Answer (score 0):

> Jetzt reden wir Klartext.

ist eine ganz ähnliche Formulierung auf Deutsch.

Answer (score -2):

Im Deutschen ist es eigentlich unüblich, Dinge zu sagen, die absolut offensichtlich sind. Niemand steht an der Bushaltestelle und sagt zu einem der anderen Wartenden:

> Wir warten hier.

Alle wissen, dass das so ist, also wozu soll man das noch sagen?

Außerdem reden die beiden ja schon seit mindestens vier Sätzen miteinander. Wozu sollte man also im fünften Satz aussprechen, dass man jetzt redet oder spricht.

Das macht keinen Sinn. Sinnvoller wären diese Alternativen für den fünften Satz:

> - Danke, ich werde sie mir merken.
> - Danke, dann werde ich dich demnächst mal anrufen.
> - Oh, das war einfach, deine Nummer zu bekommen.

Übrigens würde ich »to talk« eher als »reden« übersetzen. »Sprechen« ist »to speak«. Aus »Now we are talking« würde ich daher »Jetzt reden wir« machen. Siehe: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5099/1487
Aber im beschriebenen Kontext machen weder »wir reden« noch »wir sprechen« einen Sinn.

Comment: Das verfehlt das Thema, weil du die englische Wendung _Now we are talking_ nicht verstanden bzw. mißverstanden hast – [Erläuterung im Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=now+we%27re+talking) (Der OP hat natürlich auch nicht erläutert, was sie bedeutet oder sie überhaupt im Text der Frage erwähnt …) Häufig paßt etwas wie „Da kommen wir der Sache doch näher“, daher auch mein Kommentar; in diesem Fall aber nicht hundertprozentig, da die Sache ja schon vollkommen erledigt ist ([falls die Nummer stimmt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EryxH_ArIOc) jedenfalls).

Comment: +1 für "falls die Nummer stimmt..."

Comment: @chirlu: Diese Bedeutung kannte ich tatsächlich nicht. Da dies hier aber kein Englisch-Forum ist, läge es wohl am Fragesteller, die Bedeutung einer Phrase, sofern sie nicht aus der Bedeutung der einzelnen Bestandteile geschlussfolgert werden kann, anzuführen.